# Your device ran into a problems. And it needs to restart

Tags: windows-10, bios, windows-registry

I am getting an error of “Your system ran into a problem. Need a restart”. Here when I try to do restart it’s just looping the error again and again. I tried all the options such as tried to change to the recovery mode but it’s not going into that stage. Even I tried command prompt solution as well but in that whenever I run command dir into regback it doesn’t shows me all the system, default, sam and 2 other files. So couldn’t go for that option and even I tried to restore the system as well but still showing the same error.

Please help me out!!!

Comment: Can you please paste an error code, etc? As it stands No one on the internet can be sure what has happened unless they have physical access to the computer. So you got to help us out. Give us all the information, even if it is trivial.

Comment: Think of it as a detective novel. Currently, I seem to not know enough to solve your problem. Also, add some screenshots. Along with giving us info, please do contact anyone nearby who may be in a better position to help you than us.

Comment: Whenever i try to start the laptop it just go into automatic repair. I tried to do troubleshooting and restoring the pc but it’s not doing that. I tried to change the registery backup from cmd, it’s not even happening. I tried to go into safe mode via system repair but it just doesn’t go into the safe mode. The only thing I get is your system needs to restart and ran into a problem.